# asp.net MVC Herança entre Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, herança

Estou tentando implementar um cadastro de pessoa onde tenha as heranças para pessoa física e jurídica, porém o meu método salvar não está recebendo o tipo da pessoa adequadamente.

segue código de exemplo

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Salvar(PessoaViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (model is PessoaFisicaViewModel)
            await SalvarPessoaFisica(context, model as PessoaFisicaViewModel);
        else if (model is PessoaJuridicaViewModel)
            await SalvarPessoaJuridica(context, model as PessoaJuridicaViewModel);
        else await SalvarPessoa(context, model);

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

ao clicar no salvar de pessoa física ou jurídica o meu método está recebendo como sempre fosse o tipo Pessoa, nunca a herança.

Pessoa.cshtml

```
@model PessoaViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                @if (Model.PessoaId > 0)
                {
                    <label>Edição da pessoa - @Model.Nome</label>
                }
                else
                {
                    <label>Cadastro de pessoa</label>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Salvar", "Pessoa"))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    if (Model is PessoaFisicaViewModel)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("_PessoaFisica", Model)
                    }
                    else if (Model is PessoaJuridicaViewModel)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("_PessoaJuridica", Model)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("_Pessoa", Model)
                    }

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Index")" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw"></i> Voltar</a>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save fa-fw"></i> Salvar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ajax")
}
```

_PessoaFisica.cshtml

```
@model PessoaFisicaViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.PessoaId)
@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Ativo)

<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CpfCnpj, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CpfCnpj, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CpfCnpj, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RgNumero, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RgNumero, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RgNumero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

_PessoaJuridica.cshtml

```
@model PessoaViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.PessoaId)
@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Ativo)

<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CpfCnpj, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CpfCnpj, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CpfCnpj, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => (model as PessoaJuridicaViewModel).NomeFantasia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => (model as PessoaJuridicaViewModel).NomeFantasia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => (model as PessoaJuridicaViewModel).NomeFantasia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => (model as PessoaJuridicaViewModel).InscricaoMunicipal, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => (model as PessoaJuridicaViewModel).InscricaoMunicipal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => (model as PessoaJuridicaViewModel).InscricaoMunicipal, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Models

```
public interface IPessoa
    {
        bool Ativo { get; set; }
        string CpfCnpj { get; set; }
        string Nome { get; set; }
        int PessoaId { get; set; }
    }
    public class PessoaViewModel : IPessoa
    {
        public bool Ativo { get; set; }
        public string CpfCnpj { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    }

    public interface IPessoaFisica : IPessoa
    {
        int? RgNumero { get; set; }
    }

    public class PessoaFisicaViewModel : PessoaViewModel, IPessoaFisica
    {
        public int? RgNumero { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IPessoaJuridica : IPessoa
    {
        string InscricaoMunicipal { get; set; }

        string NomeFantasia { get; set; }
    }

    public class PessoaJuridicaViewModel : PessoaViewModel, IPessoaJuridica
    {
        public string InscricaoMunicipal { get; set; }

        public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Como estão seus *Models*?

Comment: Adicionado os models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modelagem está correta, mas não entendi por que *ViewModels* são tratados como *Models* no seu sistema.

Se a geração do banco de dados foi feita corretamente, haverá uma tabela `Pessoas` com todos os campos combinados de `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica`, mais uma coluna chamada `Discriminator`, que indica qual o tipo da entidade, se física ou jurídica.

Já no caso da *Action* `Salvar`, aí sim você deveria usar um *ViewModel* com todos os campos das duas classes, e montar o objeto correspondente ao tipo da pessoa em *Controller*, e não mandar o objeto primitivo para o *Controller* e tentar converter. O *binding* dos campos é feito em cima da classe colocada como argumento da *Action*, e ela não entende herança. Por isso você não tem os valores na hora de converter o objeto.

Comment: é que faço com que cada entidade seja uma tabela, então tenho as tabelas Pessoa, PessoaFisica e PessoaJuridica.

Comment: Além de não justificar, está errado. Uma Pessoa Física não pode ser também uma Pessoa Jurídica ao mesmo tempo, o que torna a herança o mais recomendado. *ViewModels* não são *Models*. Não podem ser objetos de bancos de dados. São modelos de dados usados para recolher e tratar dados, e por isso há essa separação.